# Validate textarea when clicking submit

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am developing website that allow user sending feedback to system. I have created feedback form by using textarea and button for submit. In most important thing is when user click on submit, if user input some words that I don't want them to input, that feedback won't send to the system; it will alert user to drop out that word before cicking submit.

Since now, i just create a simple code that will echo some warning if user input the word that i don't want them to input in feedback form.

***Here is my code***

```
<form action="main.php" method="post">
    <textarea cols='10' rows='5' name='text'></textarea>
    <br/>
    <input type='submit' name='add' Value='Add to list' />
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
    $banned = array('dog', 'cat', 'cow'); // Add more
    $entry = $_POST['add'];
    foreach($banned as $word): if (strpos($entry, $word) !== false) die('Contains banned word');
    endforeach;
}
?>
```

It is not work. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Google profanity checker there are plenty of plugins that will do this for you.

Comment: @Sovat may my answer will help you a bit

Answer (score 2):

Try like

```
$entry = $_POST['text'];    // Not $_POST['add'];
foreach ($banned as $word):
    if (strpos($entry, $word) !== false) {
        echo 'Contains banned word';
        exit;
    }
endforeach;
```

Your `$entry` will be the text box value i.e. **$_POST['text']** `not` $_POST['add']

Answer (score 0):

USE in_array function http://php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php

```
$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
if (in_array("Irix", $os)) {
    echo "Got Irix";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of submitting the code to the server every time text is entered, I suggest you use Javascript at the client end and submit it only if it has passed the validation.

HTML

```
<form action="main.php" method="post">
<input type="text" onchange="validate_function(this)">
 //works with text area too.
<input type='submit' name='add' Value='Add to list' />
</form>
```

Javascript

```
validate_function(a)
{
r=0;
banned = array('dog', 'cat', 'cow');
var lines = a.val().split('\n');
for(var x=0;x<banned.length;x++) 
{    
for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++)
{
if (lines[i].indexOf(banned[x]) > -1)
 {
      r=1;
      break;
}
 else 
{

}

}
if(r==1)
break;
}
if( r==0)
return true;
else 
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add'])){
    $banned = array('dog', 'cat', 'cow'); // Add more
    $entry = $_POST['text'];

    if(in_array($entry,$banned))
    {
        die('Contains banned word');
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to do word censoring. To accomplish this use str_ireplace() function. I am giving a sample code for it below. What this function do is replacing the word with another.

```
<?php
$find=array('galaxy', 'planet', 'moon');
$replace=array('spiral', 'earth', 'satelite');
if (isset($_POST['userinput'])&&!empty($_POST['userinput']))
{
$user=$_POST['userinput'];
$user_new=str_ireplace($find, $replace, $user);
echo $user_new;

}
?>
<hr>
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
<textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="userinput"><?php echo $user; ?></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to stop the form submission if the user has any forbidden word

```
<form action="main.php" method="post">
<textarea cols='10' rows='5' name='text' id='text'></textarea>
<br/>
<input type='submit' name='add' Value='Add to list' onclick='validate()' />
</form>
```

in your javascript

```
<script>
function validate() {
   var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
   var banned = new Array('dog', 'cat', 'cow');
   for (var x in banned) {
      if ( strpos(text,banned[x],0) ) {
            continue; // will stop the loop
            return false; // will stop everything and will not let the form post to php

      }
   }
   return true; // will return true and will post the form to php
}

// Custom Function
function strpos (haystack, needle, offset) { // http://phpjs.org/functions/strpos/
  var i = (haystack + '').indexOf(needle, (offset || 0));
  return i === -1 ? false : i;
}
</script>
```

I hope this will help

PS: The function `strpos` has been taken from the [phpjs.org](http://phpjs.org/functions/strpos/)